# How to view .png file on Linux VM (Fedora/RHEL) running on Windows 7 host?

Tags: png, virtual-machine, virtualbox, libpng

I want to open .png file on my VirtualBox Fedora VM running on Windows 7 host? Is there a way to view the file using command line?

Note: I have tried `display ####.png` as well as `less ####.png`. Installed ImageMagick and have libpng version 1.5.9 successfully installed over my VM.

Below is the error message for `display`

[hue@sandbox ~]$ display -size 1280x1024 -window root ####.png
**display: unable to open X server `' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/424.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this approach to work, you need to have a windowing environment to render the image in.

You can either:

- run an X server in the virtual machine *or*
- [run an X server on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453/what-is-a-good-and-free-x-server-for-windows), then SSH from Windows to the VM (with X tunnelling enabled) before running `display`

---

Alternatively, share the file over the network (e.g. use VMWare's shared file systems, or run Samba or use an HTTP server) and view the image using a Windows image viewer.

---

Alternatively, [convert the image to ASCII Art](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18352/is-there-a-command-line-program-that-can-output-ascii-art-as-an-image) so it can be displayed on a console.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used Mobaxterm and installed Python plugin. It worked perfectly.